# Get multiselect values in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to get multiselsect values in PHP. This is my code:

```
<select id="tableset" class="form-control select2 table_id" name="table_id[]">
  <option value="">Table</option>
  <?php foreach ($tables as $tbls) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tbls->id; ?>"><?php echo $tbls->name; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

now to receive the values this is what i am doing

```
foreach ($_GET['table_id'] as $selectedOption)
{
  echo $selectedOption;
}
```

I get an error with invalid argument for foreach. Please help me. How can I sort the issue?

Comment: Are you looking for $_POST?

Comment: $_get is working fr rest f the form

Answer (score 0):

First for a multiple select you need to indicate it by adding multiple tag to the select

```
 <select id="tableset" multiple="multiple" class="form-control select2 table_id" name="table_id[]">
    <option value="">Table</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($tables as $tbls) {
     ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tbls->id; ?>"><?php echo $tbls->name; ?> 

   </option>
  <?php } ?>
```

now you can get them

```
foreach ($_GET['table_id'] as $selectedOption){
   echo $selectedOption;
 }
```

Comment: actually the value i am receiving is string